# Debug Assertion Failed: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use) making a copy of an ABC's reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working on a project in C++ and its structure is the following:

ABC A, Derived (public inheritance) class B, Derived (public inheritance)  class C.
composed class D, whose private member data is: vector> matr.

This is my constructor in D:

```
D(A& o, const size_t& num, const string& element, const double& last, const func_t& function)
{
    vector<double> vec = function(o[element], last, num);
    **A& p(o);
    shared_ptr<A> u(&p);**
    vector<shared_ptr<A>> matrix(num, u);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != matrix.size(); ++i)
    {
        matrix[i]->operator[](element) = vec[i];
    }
    matr = matrix;
}
```

what I am trying to do here is to create a vector of smart pointers to a **COPY** of the input A.
The reason why I am trying to get a copy is that in the for loop I modify the object being pointed, but I do not want to modify the original object I use as input. I tried to use: const A& o, but then I do not manage to use the for loop.

In main.cpp, I'd like to:

```
B opt;
cout << B["U"] << endl; // output: 60
D(B, 3, "U", 80, my_function);
cout << B["U"] << endl; // output: 60, but here instead (without trying to make a copy, bold part of the code, I get 80 because D() modifies the original A& opt )
```

So I inserted the bold part of the code to try making a copy, but I get:
Debug Assertion Failed
is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)

I cannot use template to perform this task.

Comment: I suggest you should provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)to reproduce the issue. I suggest you could refer to the link:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586144/debug-assertion-failed-expression-is-block-type-validheader-block-use)